# Cart system in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, shopping-cart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am building a shopping cart system with flutter bloc. I have a list of products and now I am adding new products to the list. It is working fine. But I want to increment the count of an item if it exists inside the list.

```
  Stream<CartState> _mapCartItemAddedToState(
    CartItemAdded event,
    CartState state,
  ) async* {
    if (state is CartLoaded) {
      try {
        yield CartLoaded(
          cart: Cart(items: List.from(state.cart.items)..add(event.item)),
        );
      } on Exception {
        yield CartError();
      }
    }
  }

  Stream<CartState> _mapCartItemIncrementedToState(
      CartItemIncremented event, CartState state) async* {
    if (state is CartLoaded) {
      List<Item> items = List.from(state.cart.items);
      var index = items.indexWhere((item) => item.id == event.id);
      items[index].count++;

      try {
        yield CartLoaded(cart: Cart(items: items));
      } on Exception {
        yield CartError();
      }
    }
  }
```

These are two states I am using. First is adding the product directly while the second reassigns the list after updating the item that inside of the list. The problem I have is my count states are not updating. I have used equatable. All dependencies are included. Is this approach correct or should I go for another way of doing it? I cannot realise how it can be done. My page is updating only after I refresh it.

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I've built the Shopping App Prototype that uses BLoC for state management. This project solves the exact same problem. You could find the example of the Cart BLoC (together with project repository) here: https://github.com/mkobuolys/shopping-app-prototype/blob/main/lib/modules/cart/bloc/cart_bloc.dart